# KeyboardViewshow will move button up

Tags: java, android

Is it possible to push a set of buttons up immediately when the CustomKeyboard is shown? So as to say the buttons position is dependent on the KeyBoardView.

Currently what I have is:
http://puu.sh/aM7yV/d08f5711e4.jpg

But when my KeyboardView comes up, the BACK and NEXT button will be behind it basically.
http://puu.sh/aM7ya/fd33d398e1.jpg

Instead of that, I want them to be just right on top of the KeyboardView borders.

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/nextselection"
android:layout_width="200dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:text="@string/next" />

  <Button
  android:id="@+id/backselection"
  android:layout_width="200dp"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
  android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
  android:text="@string/back" />

   <android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView
   android:id="@+id/keyboardview"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
   android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
   android:focusable="true"
   android:visibility="gone" />
```

Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Set android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" in the manifest.  That will tell the app to resize to fit the remaining area.  The alternative is to put it into pan mode, where it only moves the app up enough to ensure the carret is on the screen.

Comment: DO I put that under the Application tag or the activity tag of the Manifest file ?

Comment: I tried to put on Activity tag of the activity it is in. But the button still stayed behind the custom keyboard though